# I want to split the string on the base of multiple separators and keep the value and key in an object

Tags: javascript

**Sample String**

> "<#>https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fabulinus-app.appspot.
>   com/o/TestingFacts%2Fhuman-heart-health-illustration.jpg?alt=
>   media&token=98d83908-0d84-4fb2-ac6e-4918618e2db6<#> <&>The heart is
>   part of your body’s circulatory system. It’s made up of the atria,
>   ventricles, valves,  and various arteries and veins. The main function
>   of your heart is to keep blood that’s  full of oxygen circulating
>   throughout your body. Because your heart is crucial to your  survival,
>   it’s important to keep it healthy with a well-balanced diet and
>   exercise, and avoid  things that can damage it, like smoking.<&>
>   <#>https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fabulinus-app.appspot.com/o/TestingFacts%2F10-
>   Essential-Facts-About-Heart-Failure-1440x810.jpg?alt=media&token=45e10991-065e-4e3b
>   -b5f2-9df6f723fb5a<#> <&>Your heart affects every part of your body. That also means that diet, lifestyle, and your  emotional well-being
>   can affect your heart. Emotional and physical health are both
>   important  for maintaining a healthy heart.<&> <@>Read more: Healthy
>   heart tips<@>
>   <#>https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fabulinus-app.appspot.com/o/TestingFacts%
>   2Fimages%20(4).jpg?alt=media&token=275488d3-fc24-4763-9349-780593e59fe0<#>"

I want to arrange the keys and value in an object

**Required Result**

```
    [{
key : "<#>",
value:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fabulinus-app.appspot. com/o/TestingFacts%2Fhuman-heart-health-illustration.jpg?alt= media&token=98d83908-0d84-4fb2-ac6e-4918618e2db6"
},{
key : "<&>",
value : "The heart is part of your body’s circulatory system. It’s made up of the atria, ventricles, valves, and various arteries and veins. The main function of your heart is to keep blood that’s full of oxygen circulating throughout your body. Because your heart is crucial to your survival, it’s important to keep it healthy with a well-balanced diet and exercise, and avoid things that can damage it, like smoking."
}]
```

I have been trying with multiple separators that split the string but I am unable to keep the record of which key belong to which substring.

By Using a simple split function

```
split(/(<#>)/)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried, as this website is not a code writing service

Comment: That won't work as your keys will be overwritten. You can't have an object with duplicate keys. Also.. what have you tried?

Comment: NP, that's what this website is here for. Please [edit] the question and include the code you're having difficulties with

Comment: Some guy use this regex "arg&&(arg||(!arg&&arg))".split(/([()]|&&|\|\|)/) but this was not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is simple code with which you can start:

```
function tokenizer(text) {
    var regexp = /(<[#&@]>)([^<>]+)<[#&@]>/g;
    var match;
    var result = {};
    while(match = regexp.exec(text)) {
        if(!result[match[1]]) {
            result[match[1]] = [];
        }
        result[match[1]].push(match[2])
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test it for some edge cases.

For example current values can't use '<>' symbols (we use non <> symbols to detect values).

<#>test<@> will be also considered as a normally closed tag.

But hope this helps! ;)